# Applying firewall rules to a specific tag in google cloud didn't work

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I have a spring boot application deployed to an app engine service. The instance tag for this application is my_tag, this is configured inside the app.yaml file:

```
network:
  instance_tag: my_tag
```

I created a few firewall rules with a target tag "my_tag" but non of them worked except one (the only one) which is deny all request (IP ranges: 0.0.0.0/0), this rule worked fine and it worked  for one tag (my_tag), which is exactly what I want. 
Note: even with making the priority higher for other rules, they also didn't work.

Comment: Can you please clarify which kind of service and language you are using? (Standard, flexible; python,java,etc...)

Comment: Language: Java. Environment: flexible. @Ggrimaldo

Comment: Can you please specify how did you create the firewall rule with the target tag "my_tag"?. It won't allow me to create a target tag "my_tag". 

I get "Invalid tag: my_tag. Tags must contain only lowercase letters, numbers and hyphens."

Comment: I apologize, it's "my-tag". It's hyphen. 
I created the rule by going to 'VPC network', then 'Firewall rules', and finally 'create firewall rule'

Comment: So far I've tested the VPC it has worked without problems for my App Engine App. What is exactly what has failed for you? , how did you test that?, from which service are you trying to connect? , what are exactly the rules you are setting?.

Comment: @Ggrimaldo, Could you please let me know what exactly you did?

Comment: I've created a GCE VM together with my browser and I've tested the connectivity from it to my App engine App, either for allowing or denying and it has worked without problems. Could it be that you are setting these rules on the "Networking" section?. Please note that firewall for App engine is configured at COMPUTE ->App Engine-> Firewall rules

Comment: @Ggrimaldo. I didn't choose the app engine firewall because it's gonna be applied to all services under the app engine. I wanted to apply the rule only to one service (not all). However, after searching about this issue, I found that it's not applicable to apply a firewall rule to a specific app engine service. 
Thanks for your help. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

I am very glad to be of help. I've found feature request in the [public issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/110763628) of Google in which another user is also asking for the creation of a specific set of rules for a specific service.

As explained there, a possible workaround would be to deploy the backend service to a project where the GAE Firewall rules prevent any requests except the other GAE services or to check that the requests are coming from the right service by adding an additional payload to the request.